# Need to convert string into hash and then Hash into string

Tags: ruby, hash

I am passing an argument as shown below

```
def hi value

   value=(here I need to convert back to Hash from string)

   puts value['key']

end

hi "h['key']" #I am passing hash as string
```

I am passing Hash as string and I need to convert back to hash as I have shown above,Is it possible? The reason I am asking this is because the error handling part has to be performed within function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what the format of your string would be from your question but I will assume you mean a string containing a ruby literal Hash definition. For example:

```ruby
hash_string = "{ 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'Fabricio' }"
```

First of all it is best practice to define a method in ruby with arguments in parentheses:

```ruby
def to_hash(string)
  # Contents of method
end
```

You can interpret the string as if you were defining it in a ruby file using `eval` (assuming the string is valid ruby syntax), and thus the function could look something like this:

```ruby
def to_hash(string)
  eval(string)
end

hash = to_hash("{ 'id' => 3, 'name' => 'Fabricio' }")

puts hash['id'] # => 3
puts hash['name'] # => "Fabricio"
```

I hope this is what you intended and is of some use to you.

Comment: hi, Thank you, this is the answer I need, exactly this 'eval' function is what I was searching!!